# The icon for your application is not valid. Please use a 48x48 PNG

Tags: android, google-play

"The icon for your application is not valid. Please use a 48x48 PNG." When I tried to upload my app , it shows the above error.  Also I found some answers about the "\n" in String.xml file...have to change app_name.... But For me, I do n't use any \n in string.xml. I use 48*48 png  icon for my app . Kindly help me to overcome this error.

Comment: Are you sure your application icon is a valid 48x48 png image?  Try opening it in paint or preview or something and make sure that it actually opens and is the right size.

Comment: Yes it's size is 48*48 PNG. I checked it twice .

Comment: Can you try another file first? Create or google.com/images a random 48*48 png and check if that works